# Reference to understand Animations and graphics in Android

Tags: java, android, animation, graphics, opengl-es

I have not done Animation and Graphics programming till now, but interested in that field.

I am looking at few codes for animations(Canvas) and open gl es graphics,
So everything ends up with good tutorials which basically tells
how to use Android or open GL ES API's to draw polygons and basic units.

But usually get stuck in 2nd or 3rd tutorial because many things which are being used
I am not able to understand like , why set frame buffer , clear the buffer.
Some bits are set and some are unset!

So the problem clearly here is I don't know the basics of it when comes to Graphics and Animations! 
Which is the good resource to understand these stuffs. Not the usage part but one can say internals of it ! What is frame buffer , what are essential components and basics in graphics and Animations. What is FPS? What is rendering? ...

I am thinking of going through some Computer Graphics lecture. Anything else one should look to understand all these basics which will ultimately lead to better understanding of graphics and open gl es programming ?

I am interested to know about Books, Blogs, online tutorials in this field.

Answer (score 0):

may be this could help you

http://www.droidnova.com/2d-tutorial-series-part-i,770.html